# Need to pass parameters and css using Html.Actionlink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call a controller method using an ActionLink. I can access the controller method, and even use css to make the ActionLink look like the button it's supposed to, but I can't pass in parameters - every time I try, I either get an error or the values turn up as null.

These will actually reach the method and hit the break point I set, but without any parameter values.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Request", "Create", "HomeController",  new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})</p>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Request", "Create", "HomeController",  new { @class = "btn btn-primary", title = "hello", description = "world"})</p>
```

These give me an error as soon as I click on the button, specifically an HTTP 404 error for /HomeController/Create.

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Request", "Create", "HomeController", new { title = "hello", description = "world" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})</p>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Request", "Create", "HomeController", new { @class = "btn btn-primary"}, new { title = "hello", description = "world" })</p>
```

Here's the method in HomeController for the sake of completeness"

```
    public ActionResult Create(string title, string description)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Index2");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: If your controller is named "HomeController" then the ActionLink helper will use the string "Home" for the controller parameter.

Comment: @Jasen oh my god thank you that did the trick at long last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is using this version of the overload

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Submit Request",
                 actionName: "Create",
                 routeValues: "HomeController",
                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

The second version of your attempt cannot find the "/HomeController/Create" so unless your controller is `HomeControllerController` you'll need to drop "Controller" from the `controllerName`.

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Submit Request",
                 actionName: "Create",
                 controllerName: "Home",
                 routeValues: new { title = "hello", description = "world" },
                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```